# Can fighting in a confined space be a realistic strategy?

Tags: self-defense, streetfight, strategy

I've been watching the [following breakdown](https://youtu.be/9DBRbx-qvgE?t=241) of Jet Li's famous final fight in the Kiss of the Dragon, and it made me question whether if you're being attacked by a certain type of opponent if a viable strategy would be to use a confined space to your advantage in a similar way?

Specifically what kind of attacks would be harder for the opponent to use against you (kicking is featured in the clip), and how would you have to fight to make sure you get the most out of the confined space? For example I would think using a bladed stance would make movement easier in a long confined space such as this since it is ideal for moving forward and backwards, and it is easier to slip through narrower areas when more sideways.

In [another fight scene](https://youtu.be/ed6b2X1De4I?t=67) (also with Jet Li) a different type of confined space is used which I feel is quite interesting in that in the first clip ground grappling would probably not work very well, yet in the low clearance clip it could be very effective.

What is a more viable strategy? Is it always better to fight in an open space, or can luring an opponent into a confined space also be a good strategy?

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on who you are fighting and why.  Most people don't get into fights much.  In any self defence situation the last thing you want to do is get into a confined space.  This is because injuring the attacker is not your goal.  Your goal is to avoid harm.  Usually the best way to avoid harm is to escape (ie get as far away from the source of harm as is practical).  Similarly there is no reason to do this in a situation involving weapons (any war/military situation).  In combat sports it's obviously not possible either unless you are doing Car Jujitsu or similar.

Much as I love Jet Li films they are not at all realistic in terms of what violence looks like... Just look at how contrived the plot has to be to make him fight at all.

That said... Using a doorway or narrow corridor to your advantage is a viable self defence strategy against multiple attackers.  So long as one is available and so long as there are no better escape options.

Comment: For personal experience with multiple attackers (although not in a real fight), when I was sparring three black belts during a tae kwon do test, I constantly maneuvered myself so only one person could engage me and was in the way of the other two. Even when the two tried to split around the "front" attacker, I switched my target and made them an obstacle to the other two. Over 20 years later, I still find their frustration hilarious. The three "attackers" spent more time fighting each other trying to get to me than they did fighting me. Space wasn't confined, but their ability to attack was.

Comment: @computercarguy Yes that's all good... We practice this in the dojo and it's also a thing in a lot of gradings. But it's not as easy as fighting 3 people one at a time in a narrow corridor.

Comment: @computercarguy The scenario where you know your are attacked by three guys, they are coming from the same direction, and have the 10x10 metres (minimum) to constantly outmaneuvre them is not realistic in self-defense.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking I agree. Its not a bad drill though.

Comment: Yep, I realize that training and sparring only goes so far in a real situation, that's why we practice so many different scenarios. Becoming a true master involves doing the correct form, but also doing moves without form. In one of Jackie Chan's "Drunken Master" films, we see him fighting under a train station with spears and swords, which isn't something people specifically train for, but a sufficiently well trained person can figure out along the way. And, as you say, in self-defense the idea is to get away from, rather than injure, the attacker.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking, you are absolutely correct, although the sparring area I was in was occupied by at least 6 other sparring groups without borders, so we had to avoid each other, too. Also, the three black belts started off spread out over about 120 degrees in front of me, so not exactly the same direction. I had to engineer that. Many of the other groups did end up having the black belts completely surround the tester, which I wasn't going to let happen to me. I'm simply saying that getting multiple attackers into a self-confined space can be a useful tactic.

Comment: Some very interesting points here. @HuwEvans could you possibly update your answer to reflect a situation where you are inside, lets say in an office or normal residential space which lacks open space but have no way of escape and are therefore forced to choose in which environment/room you need to face the attacker, and there is no element of surprise in your benefit. I think that is the closest circumstances to the scenes above.

Comment: @FrontEnd the best thing to do in either situation is to grab an object and use it as a weapon. Or more likely allow the guy with the gun to take your belongings and claim on insurance later. Situations where unarmed attackers break into buildings are very unlikely.

Comment: If you are working in a needle exchange or whatever you may have to deal with situations but even then this is a rather unlikely strategy to use.

Answer (score 2):

From an armed fighting, specifically Historic European Martial Arts, "HEMA," perspective, opting for a limited space is a totally valid choice. ***Context*** is important here!

Limited space allows for you to fight multiple opponents by simply limiting the number of people you must engage at once. When you see one person fighting multiple opponents in open spaces, this is the exact reason there is so much movement. An narrow ally or doorway produces the same effect.

Additionally, certain weapons do better or worse in certain environments. Spears may be the king of the open battlefield, but a dagger or short sword will serve you better indoors. Confined spaces also affect things like grappling: the wall is a reasonably hard surface one can use for support or to smash enemies against.

As a final note about confined spaces, they are great to enter when attempting to counter ranged or mounted foes. The word *mounted* will also apply to vehicles here.

Tanks *could* burst through houses like they are made of paper, but a humble root cellar will trap them. A car *may* drive through a wall, but it is unlikely to go much further. A horse *could* go into a city, but it's not going down steps or into too-narrow doorways.

Limited sight and maneuverability in cities are still a bane to modern militaries trying to move through them, as one can easily be flanked or ambushed. This applies to most ranged weapons at the individual level, too. It doesn't take much imagination to see why a dagger is as good or better than a gun in an apartment or home.

Comment: Thank you for that perspective